# Drupal default views versus Views contrib module

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Drupal has some built in views that work without `Views` contrib module. We even can not manage or alter them. `frontpage` and `taxonomy_term` are two examples of such views. They are known as default views.

How can we generate our own views via module development?

My other question is about `Views` contrib module.

How `views` module enhances drupal's capabilities about views?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Built-in list pages in Drupal (like the one listing all nodes) are strictly speaking not "views", because they are not powered by the Views module. After installing the Views module, you can replace the built-in list pages with your own views or add custom views for administrative tasks.

If you download version 3 (in alpha at the moment) of the [admin_menu module](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) you will also get the admin_views module, which can replace all built-in lists with 'real' views.

If you want to learn how to include a default view in your module, see this [blog post](http://prajwalaa.wordpress.com/2009/06/20/providing-default-view-with-your-module/).

Comment: Marc is very correct. Broadly speaking, you refer to a view as an arranged display of content. The stock features you refer to are hard coded in their respective modules (taxonomy and so on).

That being said, the Views module GREALY expands the way in which you display content in Drupal, it is essential for thousands of websites. You can control how much, what of and in what style you display one or many content types, users, taxonomy terms, files, flags, etc.  It's really a great module.